# 'I want to catch up with all of you'

Tags: meaning

I don't know what this sentence means:

> I want to catch up with all of you.

Could you give me the example situation that this sentence is used in?

Comment: I edited your question. You are the one who should include any situation.

Comment: I saw this sentence in the drama but I just saw this part only and I don't know what the situation was. Because of this, I wanted to know what this means. :)

Comment: Without context it's just a guess, but I reckon the speaker was addressing a number of people, and expressed a desire to catch up with all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*Note:* There is not enough information in the question to know for sure what the context is. However, this is a common phrase that is frequently found in a certain context: namely, when one person is speaking with acquaintances (usually friends) that he/she hasn't seen in a long time. I am going to assume this is the intended context.]

To "catch up with" in this context means to get reacquainted or to reconnect with a person (usually a friend) after an absence. It's used to imply that one wants to engage in extended conversation with someone to talk about what has happened in each other's lives since the last time they had a significant conversation.

An example scenario would be:

> A: Oh, hi! I didn't know you worked here! You look great!
>
> B: Thank you so much; you too. Actually several other members of our old chess club work here too.
>
> A: That's great! I want to catch up with all of you. It's been so long! How about we all go to dinner tonight so that we can catch up on everything that has happened in the years since I last saw you?

Compare this to "bringing someone up to speed," which has a similar but more pragmatic and formal meaning.

*Note to other posters: My original thought was that this was a simple case of "check the dictionary!" But the first 3 or 4 online dictionaries I searched all returned definitions with negative consequences (the police caught up with him, his mistakes caught up with him, etc.). It is highly unlikely that the speaker is a cop chasing some robbers ("I am in my police car chasing you and I want to catch up with all of you bad guys!") or an inanimate object or concept ("I am a flu virus, and all of these students have been working so hard and worn down their immune systems. I want to catch up with all of you and make you sick after staying up late studying so many nights in a row and not getting sufficient sleep!"). So I think that this is a worthy question to ask.*

Comment: I am sorry, but there is no context in the question.

Comment: @Rathony You are correct; there is no context. I will edit my answer to indicate my assumptions about context.

Comment: I understand your answer and +1.

Comment: Wow! The example situation is so great that I got what it means. Thank you!!